# Google Cloud resumable upload in PHP - How does it differ programmatically from regular upload?

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I have a Google Cloud upload function that works fine with the relatively small files I've been uploading (see code below). But I will soon need to be uploading files up to 500Meg in size and I was looking into the "resumable" upload option. On the Google Documentation it says basically that files over 5Meg and Google just converts the upload to a resumable upload type. But what does that mean? Does that mean I don't have to make any coding changes? Does it mean that if my page times out and I re-invoke the page and start the download again, that Google API will automatically detect that the previous upload failed and will just simply resume the upload where it left off and then only return a valid (non-NULL) storageObject to me once the upload completes?

Here is my current "non-resumable" code:

```
function uploadFile($bucketName,&$fileContent, $cloudPath) {
    $privateKeyFileContent = $GLOBALS['privateKeyFileContent'];
    // connect to Google Cloud Storage using private key as authentication
    try {
        $storage = new StorageClient([
            'keyFile' => json_decode($privateKeyFileContent, true)
        ]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // maybe invalid private key ?
        print $e;
        return false;
    }

    // set which bucket to work in
    $bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);

    $sFileHash = base64_encode(md5($fileContent,true)); 

    $storageObject = $bucket->upload(
            $fileContent,
            [
            'name' => $cloudPath,
            'metadata' => ['md5Hash' => $sFileHash]
            ]
    );

    return $storageObject; // will be null on failure
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the differences between `upload()` and `getResumableUploader()`, we can see very strange documentation. As per documentation on [Cloud client Library](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.134.0/storage/bucket?method=upload) the upload function states:

> Upload your data in a simple fashion. Uploads will default to being
> resumable if the file size is greater than 5mb.

And as [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/resumable-uploads#php) documentation states:

> Resumable uploads are automatically managed on you behalf, but can be
> directly controlled using the resumable option.

Which means with your current code you could enable the resumable option for `upload()` in your code by adding `'resumable' => true`. Though i'm not too certain, there's probably something behind the scenes were not seeing and documentation doesnt explain clearly. This example would look something like:

```
$storageObject = $bucket->upload(
        $fileContent,
        [
        'name' => $cloudPath,
        'metadata' => ['md5Hash' => $sFileHash],
        'resumable' => true
        ]
);
```

I had a look at the [source code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php/blob/v0.134.0/Storage/src/Bucket.php#L478) on github for both of these methods and they have practically the same configuration options but `getresumableUpload()` contains `getResumeUri()` which is necessary for  `resume()`, I couldn't seem to find compatibility for normal `upload()` though I wouldn't rule it out.

```
$uploader = $bucket->getResumableUploader(
    fopen($fileContent, 'r'),
      [
      'name' => $cloudPath,
      'metadata' => ['md5Hash' => $sFileHash]
      ]
);

try {
    $object = $uploader->upload();
} catch (GoogleException $ex) {
    //if there is an error it can automatically restart
    //$uploader contains 'resumeUri' which is what is used to resume the upload
    $resumeUri = $uploader->getResumeUri();
    $object = $uploader->resume($resumeUri);
}
```

`resume()` handles all of the necessary headers and bytes sent for you to resume an upload.

The case you are describing should be resumable.

All of the following HTTP status responses are considered retryable:

- 408 Request Timeout
- 500 Internal Server Error
- 502 Bad Gateway
- 503 Service Unavailable
- 504 Gateway Timeout

The following HTTP status responses are non-retryable:

- 404 Not Found
- 410 Gone

More info on HTTP statuses [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes)